# How can I "double-click, edit and save while-leaving" a Windows Forms DataGridView CurrentCell?

Tags: c#, winforms, datagridview

I'm barely new with WinForm's DataGridView control and quite honestly I'm having a hard time trying to mix and match its events and methods (e.g. `CommitEdit()` method didn't do what I've expected) to implement the simple concept of "entering edit mode by double-clicking the cell, modify its value (hopefully doing some sort of validation) and saving changes when leaving the aforementioned cell. My actual code looks like this and it's definitely incomplete:

```
// DEBUG

private void myDataGridView_CellDoubleClick(object sender, DataGridViewCellEventArgs e)
{
    this.myDataGridView.BeginEdit(true);
    this.myDataGridView.CurrentCell.ReadOnly = false;
}

private void myDataGridView_CellLeave(object sender, DataGridViewCellEventArgs e)
{
    this.myDataGridView.EndEdit();
}

private void myDataGridView_CellBeginEdit(object sender, DataGridViewCellCancelEventArgs e)
{
    DataGridViewCellStyle editCellStyle = new DataGridViewCellStyle();
    editCellStyle.BackColor = System.Drawing.Color.DarkOrange;
    editCellStyle.ForeColor = System.Drawing.Color.Black;
    this.myDataGridView.CurrentCell.Style.ApplyStyle(editCellStyle);
}

private void myDataGridView_CellEndEdit(object sender, DataGridViewCellEventArgs e)
{
    DataGridViewCellStyle defaultCellStyle = new DataGridViewCellStyle();
    defaultCellStyle.BackColor = System.Drawing.Color.White;
    this.myDataGridView.CurrentCell.Style.ApplyStyle(defaultCellStyle);
}

// DEBUG
```

So as you might notice any help you could provide will be really valuable and definintely appreciated. Thanks much you guys in advance!

Comment: What exactly is the problem? e.g Is the datasource not being updated? Database? CellStyles not updating?

Comment: Thanks for your reply Conrad Frix. Actually nothing is being updated, despite <code>myDataGridView.CurrentCell.EditedFormattedValue</code> holds the new value, when leaving the cell it's lost.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Wow, turns out the "Entity" (LINQ-to-SQL) I'm dealing with has no PK hence LINQ is unable to update it so it's not DGV's fault. Sorry about that.

Comment: I've been able to "fake" the PK within the entity model and it works although I'm not necessarily loving the "workaround" it does the job.